# How to access the values from Prophet by Meta?

Tags: r, facebook-prophet

I am working with the Prophet library. I am trying to get the raw data that gets plotted when calling the prophet_plot_components. I basically want regressor_coefficients(m) but for the seasonality not for the extra regressors.

I tried reading the code on GitHub but no luck :(

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the forecast object is a dataframe which contains the values for regressors for each date as well as the time series components.

That won't be a simple table with one value like the regressor coefficients. But you could produce a plot of weekly seasonal values by choosing one year of values like this:

```
ggplot(subset(forecast, ds >= '2022-12-31' & ds < "2024-01-01"), aes(y = yearly, x = as.Date(ds))) +
        geom_line()
```